# BigCommerce PHP API seems really slow

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I've built a small application for our warehouse team that shows them every product that needs to be filled for the day in grouped format. It works great except it takes awhile to load.

Today we had around 192 orders with 477 products.

I'm achieving this like so...
1.) I pull all orders under a particular status_id.
2.) foreach through every order and pull product details for each product in the order
3.) each product is pushed to a final array and sorted alphabetically.
4.) Last.. I group duplicate entries and display the item count beside each unique product. (Example: 3 x 10ml Bottles of Baja Breeze at 6mg).

This entire process takes around 4-5 minutes to load. I've tried multiple things like removing the grouping / sorting feature (spits out all products in no particular order) and using CURL. Nothing seems to make it move any faster.

For those of you that require code... http://pastebin.com/eTRL6S1c.
I realize I'm not the greatest coder. But this needed to be working quickly.

Any advice on making this application process the information faster would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anyway you can avoid the nested foreach loops? I noticed that it goes three down about 3 loops. Can that be reduced to 2? I bet that is what is making it slow.

Comment: Maybe the BigCommerce-API is the bottleneck rather than your script. You should also take that into account.
There will be much more than 500 requests to the API.
I think that your high request rate could be the problem - see [Rate Limits](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/legacy/rate-limits) for more information. So try to reduce the number of requests. Perhaps you coud use some kind of pagination.

Furthermore you should try to avoid such a deep nesting of for-loops.

Comment: I would rather have less loops. However, the API doesn't allow me to filter results like I want to. If it was possible to use a custom filter. For example, filtering by a certain status ID and if the coupon discount is below 40% at the same time. Also would be nice if I could pull all of the products that are associated with my filtered orders. Thats why I'm using so many loops.

Comment: But you could improve your data structure. In line 131 for example you are adding the same string to the $product_list multiple times. It would be better to add just one entry to the list, which represents the string and quantity at the same time (you should use an object). That will reduce the amount of entries to sort an group. Could you tell me what the average quantity is? However, in this case your problem could also be the high request rate to the api. See my previous comment. Please check that bottleneck, too!

Comment: It seems that when I start looping through the orders and requesting the products associated with each order is when it starts to slow down.

Comment: Applitect, if you're requesting the products for each order, maybe you should fetch all orders first, then compile all ID's for the products in that set of orders, and make the request to each of the products at the end, which will prevent duplicate requests to products.

Comment: I think that would most likely take just as long to process. The only solution I've found is to run a cron job on a script that constantly adds new orders / products to the database. And either the application writes an html output file or it just pulls everything from the database and displays it on request. Requires writing a lot more code but it's much faster.